# A more accurate method of comparing time

Tags: javascript, json, api, time

I have JSON response from API where is date in string : e.g "2013-05-15 11:32:26"
My code is sending request every second to compare current time with time in JSON but sometimes it compares it 2 times in 1 second. Lags or something and it is sending me twice a message instead of once. If my JSON response == current date send me a message on discord (JSON is changing every now and then). Is it a more accurate method to compare that? My app is running on Heroku but it isnt server problem.

Comment: add some code, what are you exactly doing

Comment: https://pastebin.com/EgGA2JBk  179 line

Comment: Please [edit] your post and put the code there, as not everyone can access pastebin, and also please narrow down the problem - there's 250 or so lines, but no hint where to start looking.